# Can WinINet APIs be used on Windows Server OS's?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wininet

I've been looking for a quick way to download an HTML markup for a web page in my C++ code. I came across `WinINet` APIs that seem to be pretty easy to use. But then I noticed this message at the bottom of their MSDN page, say for [InternetOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Note:  WinINet does not support server implementations...

Does this mean that I can't use it if my GUI app runs on Windows Server 2008/R2/2012/R2, etc.? Can someone clarify what they meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That note means that WinINet cannot be used to implement web servers -- it can only operate as an HTTP client. It has nothing to do with the edition of Windows in use.

Comment: Oh. Because it can display (blocking) UI. That is why they also mention that it can't be used in a service. Makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Well, the issue is more that all of the functions in WinINet are all about **making** requests. There's nothing that could be used to receive and respond to an HTTP request (e.g, from a web browser).